# How to make a Signout button in Flutter with Firebase authentication?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add sign out function in my app. This app has phone authentication.
Here's the code of the home screen:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/model/image_model.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/state/state_management.dart';
import '../cloud_firestore/banner_ref.dart';
import '../cloud_firestore/lookbook_ref.dart';
import '../cloud_firestore/user_ref.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import '../model/user_model.dart';

class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDFDFDF),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              //user profile
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: getUserProfiles(context,
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber!),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    else {
                      var userModel = snapshot.data as UserModel;
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF383838)),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                              maxRadius: 30,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 30,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '${userModel.name}',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
                                        fontSize: 22,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${userModel.address}',
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.logout,
                              color: Colors.white,),
                              onPressed: () =>
                              signOut(context),),
                            context.read(userInformation).state.isStaff ?
                            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings,
                              color: Colors.white,),
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                      '/staffHome'),) : Container()
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
          //Menu
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/booking'),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.book_online,
                                size: 50,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Booking',
                                style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history'),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.history,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'History',
                              style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          //Banner
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getBanners(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                else {
                  var banners = snapshot.data as List<ImageModel>;
                  return CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          aspectRatio: 3.0,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3)),
                      items: banners
                          .map((e) => Container(
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  child: Image.network(e.image),
                                ),
                              ))
                          .toList());
                }
              }),
          //Lookbook
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Lookbook',
                  style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(fontSize: 24),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getLookbook(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null)
                  return SizedBox.shrink();
                else {
                  var lookbook = snapshot.data as List<ImageModel>;
                  return Column(
                    children: lookbook
                        .map((e) => Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                child: Image.network(e.image),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ]),
      ),
    ));
  }

  Future<void> signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    runApp(ProviderScope(
      child:
        new MaterialApp(
          home: new MyHomePage(),
        )
    )
    );

  }
}
```

and this is the main code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_ui/flutter_auth_ui.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/booking_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/done_services_screens.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/staff_home_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/user_history_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/state/state_management.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/utils/utils.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Barber Booking App',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/staffHome':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: StaffHome(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/doneService':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: DoneService(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/home':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: HomePage(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/history':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: UserHistory(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/booking':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: BookingScreen(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;

          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = new GlobalKey();

  processLogin(BuildContext context) {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      FlutterAuthUi.startUi(
              items: [AuthUiProvider.phone],
              tosAndPrivacyPolicy: TosAndPrivacyPolicy(
                  tosUrl: 'https://google.com',
                  privacyPolicyUrl: 'https://google.com'),
              androidOption: AndroidOption(
                  enableSmartLock: false, showLogo: true, overrideTheme: true))
          .then((value) async {
        //refresh state
        context.read(userLogged).state = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        //start new screen
        await checkLoginState(context, true, scaffoldState);
      }).catchError((e) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('${e.toString()}')));
      });
    } else {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            key: scaffoldState,
            body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/my_bg.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: checkLoginState(context, false, scaffoldState),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        else {
                          var userState = snapshot.data as LOGIN_STATE;
                          print(userState);
                          if (userState == LOGIN_STATE.LOGGED) {
                            return Container();
                          } else {
                            return ElevatedButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () => processLogin(context),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.phone,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              label: Text(
                                'Login with phone',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }

  Future<LOGIN_STATE> checkLoginState(BuildContext context, bool fromLogin,
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState) async {
    if (!context.read(forceReload).state) {
      await Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: fromLogin == true ? 0 : 3),
        () async {
          try {
            var token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken();
            //print('$token');
            context.read(userToken).state = token;
            CollectionReference userRef =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User');
            DocumentSnapshot snapshotUser = await userRef
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber)
                .get();
            //Force reload state
            context.read(forceReload).state = true;
            if (snapshotUser.exists) {
              Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, '/home', (route) => false);
            } else {
              var nameController = TextEditingController();
              var addressController = TextEditingController();
              Alert(
                context: context,
                title: 'Update data',
                content: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), labelText: 'Имя'),
                      controller: nameController,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.home), labelText: 'Адрес'),
                      controller: addressController,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                buttons: [
                  DialogButton(
                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  ),
                  DialogButton(
                    child: Text('Update'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //update to server
                      userRef
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber)
                          .set({
                        'name': nameController.text,
                        'address': addressController.text
                      }).then((value) async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!)
                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Update Successful!'),
                        ));
                        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                              context, '/home', (route) => false);
                        });
                      }).catchError((e) {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!)
                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$e')));
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ).show();
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
            return null;
          }
        },
      );
    }
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
        ? LOGIN_STATE.LOGGED
        : LOGIN_STATE.NOT_LOGIN;
  }
}
```

login depends on this code:

```
enum LOGIN_STATE { LOGGED, NOT_LOGIN }
```

App redirects me to the main page, but when I authenticate again, app does not send me to the home page because the user data still be saved.
When I delete this part of code in home screen:

```
    runApp(ProviderScope(
      child:
        new MaterialApp(
          home: new MyHomePage(),
        )
    )
    );
```

Sign out button works when I restart the app. But I need to autenticate without restarting app. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my own problem with this code:

Main code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_ui/flutter_auth_ui.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/booking_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/done_services_screens.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/staff_home_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/screens/user_history_screen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/state/state_management.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/utils/utils.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Barber Booking App',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/staffHome':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: StaffHome(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/doneService':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: DoneService(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/home':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: HomePage(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/history':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: UserHistory(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;
          case '/booking':
            return PageTransition(
                settings: settings,
                child: BookingScreen(),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade);
            break;

          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = new GlobalKey();

  processLogin(BuildContext context) {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      FlutterAuthUi.startUi(
          items: [AuthUiProvider.phone],
          tosAndPrivacyPolicy: TosAndPrivacyPolicy(
              tosUrl: 'https://google.com',
              privacyPolicyUrl: 'https://google.com'),
          androidOption: AndroidOption(
              enableSmartLock: false, showLogo: true, overrideTheme: true))
          .then((value) async {
        //refresh state
        context.read(userLogged).state = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        //start new screen
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
        );
      }).catchError((e) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('${e.toString()}')));
      });
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            key: scaffoldState,
            body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/my_bg.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: checkLoginState(context, false, scaffoldState),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        else {
                          var userState = snapshot.data as LOGIN_STATE;
                          print(userState);
                          if (userState == LOGIN_STATE.LOGGED) {
                            return Container();
                          } else {
                            return ElevatedButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () => processLogin(context),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.phone,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              label: Text(
                                'Регистрация по номеру телефона',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
  Future<LOGIN_STATE> checkLoginState(BuildContext context, bool fromLogin,
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState) async {
    if (!context.read(forceReload).state) {
      await Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: fromLogin == true ? 0 : 3),
        () async {
          try {
            var token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken();
            //print('$token');
            context.read(userToken).state = token;
            CollectionReference userRef =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User');
            DocumentSnapshot snapshotUser = await userRef
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber)
                .get();
            //Force reload state
            context.read(forceReload).state = true;
            if (snapshotUser.exists) {
              Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, '/home', (route) => false);
              return LOGIN_STATE.LOGGED;
            } else {
              var nameController = TextEditingController();
              var addressController = TextEditingController();
              Alert(
                context: context,
                title: 'Обновить данные',
                content: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), labelText: 'Имя'),
                      controller: nameController,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.home), labelText: 'Адрес'),
                      controller: addressController,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                buttons: [
                  DialogButton(
                    child: Text('Отмена'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  ),
                  DialogButton(
                    child: Text('Обновить'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //update to server
                      userRef
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber)
                          .set({
                        'name': nameController.text,
                        'address': addressController.text
                      }).then((value) async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!)
                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Данные успешно обновлены!'),
                        ));
                        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                              context, '/home', (route) => false);
                        });
                      }).catchError((e) {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!)
                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$e')));
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ).show();
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
            return LOGIN_STATE.NOT_LOGIN;
          }
        },
      );
    }
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
        ? LOGIN_STATE.LOGGED
        : LOGIN_STATE.NOT_LOGIN;
  }
}
```

Home screen code:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/model/image_model.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/state/state_management.dart';
import '../cloud_firestore/banner_ref.dart';
import '../cloud_firestore/lookbook_ref.dart';
import '../cloud_firestore/user_ref.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import '../model/user_model.dart';
import '../utils/utils.dart';

class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDFDFDF),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              //user profile
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: getUserProfiles(context,
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber!),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    else {
                      var userModel = snapshot.data as UserModel;
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF383838)),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                              maxRadius: 30,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 30,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '${userModel.name}',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
                                        fontSize: 22,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${userModel.address}',
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.logout,
                              color: Colors.white,),
                              onPressed: () =>
                              signOut(context),),
                            context.read(userInformation).state.isStaff ?
                            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings,
                              color: Colors.white,),
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                      '/staffHome'),) : Container()
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
          //Menu
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/booking'),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.book_online,
                                size: 50,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Запись',
                                style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history'),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.history,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'История',
                              style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          //Banner
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getBanners(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                else {
                  var banners = snapshot.data as List<ImageModel>;
                  return CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          aspectRatio: 3.0,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3)),
                      items: banners
                          .map((e) => Container(
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  child: Image.network(e.image),
                                ),
                              ))
                          .toList());
                }
              }),
          //Lookbook
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Примеры наших работ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(fontSize: 24),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getLookbook(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null)
                  return SizedBox.shrink();
                else {
                  var lookbook = snapshot.data as List<ImageModel>;
                  return Column(
                    children: lookbook
                        .map((e) => Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                child: Image.network(e.image),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ]),
      ),
    ));
  }

  Future<void> signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage())));
  }
}
```